# How to check if a substring can be found in two strings but not a third?

Tags: python-3.x, filtering

I'm trying to learn to program by having my personal project but this one problem is stumping me. I hope you can help.

This is some example data I'm working with (variable: market_list):

```
[{'MarketName': 'ETH-ADA', 'High': 0.00061957, 'Low': 0.00054578, 'Volume': 10390622.69836943},
{'MarketName': 'USDT-ADA', 'High': 0.64899993, 'Low': 0.434, 'Volume': 30152195.40488637},
{'MarketName': 'BTC-VTC', 'High': 0.00037478, 'Low': 0.00031501, 'Volume': 800033.42837477},
{'MarketName': 'BTC-ADA', 'High': 5.645e-05, 'Low': 4.73e-05, 'Volume': 124383204.30281776},
{'MarketName': 'ETH-LTC', 'High': 0.18977579, 'Low': 0.165721, 'Volume': 13687.21249759},
{'MarketName': 'BTC-LTC', 'High': 0.0170725, 'Low': 0.01478, 'Volume': 145304.12269212},
{'MarketName': 'USDT-NEO', 'High': 154.0, 'Low': 92.2, 'Volume': 257431.011762},
{'MarketName': 'ETH-NEO', 'High': 0.14278059, 'Low': 0.11397457, 'Volume': 64208.17297524}]
```

I'm trying to check this list of dictionaries for combinations of a substring to be found in other strings (with exceptions). So, for example "ETH-ADA" and "BTC-ADA" with the exception of USDT-ADA (that one I want to omit).

Right now I have something like this:

```
my_list = []
for x in market_list:
    coin = x['MarketName'].split("-")[1]
    if "USDT" not in x['MarketName']:
        if market_list.count(coin) == 2:
            my_list.append(coin)
```

But here I run into new troubles, because the USDT pairs are still in the list (and get counted), so I have to remove those. This feels like I'm brute forcing every possibility and I expect that there is a much better (and elegant!) way to approach it and I hope someone could explain to me how.

I often find myself in this situation so please explain your reasoning for your answer so I can understand the "programmer mindset" better. This is the hardest part of learning how to program for me.

Edit: as someone said in the comments it would be quite wise to explain my expected output.

I want the list mentioned above to output the pairs that have both ETH and BTC in common but not USDT, so this would give:

```
[ADA,LTC]
```

Comment: do not use `set`, `list`, `dict` , `tuple`  etc. as variable names, you are hiding the python types that way and run into trouble later on

Comment: you can use `a,b = x["MarketName"].split("-")` to decompose your split into two variables to check  both parts of your splitted key for `'USDT'` or coin or whatever

Comment: @PatrickArtner You're right of course. This is not my actual code but a lot more readable example. I'll edit it to remove any confusion about it.

Comment: @PatrickArtner The [if list.count(coin) == 2:] part is me trying to see if a substring exists twice in the list, but it's not working as you can see.

Comment: @PatrickArtner Crap you're right, I edited the example again.

Comment: I suggest you look over the guidelines on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and in particular include in your question the result you hope to get and the result you're currently getting.

Comment: @NathanVērzemnieks Thanks for the link! I will read it right away as I'm also quite new to asking questions here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data =  [{'MarketName': 'ETH-ADA', 'High': 0.00061957, 'Low': 0.00054578, 'Volume': 10390622.69836943},
{'MarketName': 'USDT-ADA', 'High': 0.64899993, 'Low': 0.434, 'Volume': 30152195.40488637},
{'MarketName': 'BTC-VTC', 'High': 0.00037478, 'Low': 0.00031501, 'Volume': 800033.42837477},
{'MarketName': 'BTC-ADA', 'High': 5.645e-05, 'Low': 4.73e-05, 'Volume': 124383204.30281776}]


countsOfADA = 0
countsOfUSDTADA= 0

for n in data:
    a,b = n["MarketName"].split("-")

    if b == "ADA":
        countsOfADA += 1
        if a == "USDT":
            countsOfUSDTADA += 1

print( countsOfADA - countsOfUSDTADA )
```

Output:

```
2
```

If you want to count some more, use `Counter()` :

```
from collections import Counter
myCounter = Counter()

for n in data:
    a,b = n["MarketName"].split("-")

    myCounter.update((a,))   # counts the first part
    myCounter.update((b,))   # counts the second part
    myCounter.update((a+"-"+b,))  # counts the complete thing

print(myCounter)
```

Output:

```
Counter({'ADA': 3, 'BTC': 2, 'ETH': 1, 'ETH-ADA': 1, 'USDT': 1, 'USDT-ADA': 1, 'VTC': 1, 'BTC-VTC': 1, 'BTC-ADA': 1})
```

Counter: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Counter works only on hashable objects and it will decompose iterables, so if you want to stuff strings in it, put them in a tuple first:

```
"abc" -> counted as 1 a , 1 b , 1 c
("abc",) -> counted as 1 "abc"-tuple which it will decompose into the string.
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This solves the problem for one coin, but how to test every coin against the ETH/USDT/BTC pairs? How can make this loop also check VTC for example?

Comment: I think that's it! I remove entries without either ETH or BTC from the list beforehand and then count the amount of entries with a certain coin. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @NoSplitSherlock  have a look at `Counter()`  and its methods.